# Why ViewData not work

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have MVC2 view in which there is a grid and image button. When image button is clicked, it will pass the data of grid's currentPage, filter and orderBy fields ... to another controller. The code is,

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MaintenanceEditableViewModel>" %>

"Image button"
<a href="<%: Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "ExportExcelButton", new { resourceId = ViewData["resourceId"], pagenum = ViewData["page"], orderBy = ViewData["orderBy"], filter = ViewData["filter"] }) %>">
<img src='<%: Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ExportExcelButton.gif") %>' /></a>

"Grid"
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<MaintenanceAthletesResultsViewModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:8pt;" })
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:335px" })
.DataKeys(k => k.Add(k2 => k2.ResultID))
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
.Select("AthletesResultsAjax", "Maintenance")
...

"Action to initialize the grid in Maintenance controller"
public ActionResult AthletesResults(string id, bool editable)
{
ViewData["resourceId"] = id;
this._resourceBL.PopulateMaintenanceResourcesViewData(id, this.SelectedSport());

MaintenanceEditableViewModel model = new MaintenanceEditableViewModel { Editable = editable };
return View(model);
}

[GridAction]
public ActionResult AthletesResultsAjax(string id, int page, string orderBy, string filter)
{
List<MaintenanceAthletesResultsViewModel> model = null;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
ViewData["page"] = page;
ViewData["orderBy"] = orderBy;
ViewData["filter"] = filter;

model = this._resourceBL.GetMaintenanceAthletesResultsViewModel(int.Parse(id));
}

return View(new GridModel(model));
}

public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string resourceId, string pagenum, string orderBy, string filter)
```

The strange thing is that only ViewData["resourceId"] (set in initialization of view) is able to be passed. The 3 parameters, ViewData["page"], ViewData["orderBy"], ViewData["filter"] (set in grid ajax action) can not be passed. All 3 are null in ExportToExcel and so I think they are not correctly stored in ViewData (I am not sure how to check ViewData when image button is pressed). I am confused and need help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how/where you're sending those arguments into the AthletesResultsAjax action. The signature of the dataBinding.Ajax().Select() function you're using only specifies the action and the controller name. How is it going to know what those values are? You need to specify a routeValues object to send the appropriate data to the controller action.  If you debug the code and put a breakpoint in your ajax action, do the actual values come through? I could be quite off here but I think your problem is more on this end than on how the data is being stored in the ViewData.

Comment: AthletesResultsAjax is called when grid page number/orderBy/filter have been changed. I checked in debug and values are correct, eg page =3 when page number goes to 3. Strangely enough, when they are accessed in Url.Action in the view through ViewData, the values are lost.

Comment: Hmmm sorry, i guess i was indeed quite off here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ViewData is mainly used pass data from Controller to View and in your case you have Controller -> View -> Controller. I think Telerik Knowledge Base has a good solution how to provide additional data to your export action. [Telerik Knowledge Base](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-mvc/grid/export-to-excel.aspx)

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "Export", new { page = 1, orderBy = "~", filter = "~"}, new { id = "exportLink" }) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBound() {
        var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
        var $exportLink = $('#exportLink');
        var href = $exportLink.attr('href');
        href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + grid.currentPage);
        href = href.replace(/orderBy=([^&]*)/, 'orderBy=' + (grid.orderBy || '~'));
        href = href.replace(/filter=(.*)/, 'filter=' + (grid.filterBy || '~'));
        $exportLink.attr('href', href);
    }
</script>
```

The script dynamically updates Export-links url when data is received & rendered (OnDataBound) to the screen. It should then bind nicely on the Controller side.

If you're more familiar with JavaScript then you should probably put an click event to the export button and make GET request in the JavaScript side. Then you don't have make that ugly looking url modifications.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I figure it out using jquery. However, it is still unclear why ViewData not working because ViewData is set in controller and should be able to be accessed in the view.

Comment: if you check the DOM using Developer Toolbar (F12 in most of the browser) the Url is not containing any parameters or contains null values?